# Should I use in or at in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

1) In my previous role as a cook at Company A ....

or

2) At my previous role as a cook in Company A ....

Which is more appropriate to write?

Comment: This question would be better asked (and get better answers) at our sister stack, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous role as a cook at General Cuisine, Inc. I focused on egg-based dishes.

The word "at" leaps to mind but I would not blink if someone used "in." The crux of the matter is that you are working at the company, while I think of someone "in" the company as being perhaps a shareholder or officer (but "at" might work there as well).

Also you might want to construct a sentence like this, and the distinction becomes more important: In my role as cook at General Cuisine... In this case "in General Cuisine" would sound awkward and even mildly ambiguous.

Comment: A role is not a place, so you can't be "at" it.  A role  is something that you "fill" (like stepping into a pair of shoes), thus, you were "in" the role.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Totally agree. My point was that if you used, "in my role as __ in X company," the repetition would sound slightly more awkward.

Comment: Sorry, I should have directed my comment to OP. You seem to have dealt well with why to use "at" with company after you substitute "in my role" but didn't explicitly say why NOT to use "at" with role.  Your answer would be better if you did. Maybe you can phrase that more elegantly than I have.